# Why do we use fractional change so much when speaking of mechanical properties of matter?

Tags: material-science

In many concepts of the mechanical properties of matter (ex : bulk modulus , youngs modulus etc) , we use the quantity of fractional change. Why do we describe the structural nature of matter using fractional change? Why is this preferred description of the phenomena, why not another?

Comment: What other concept would you propose that works?

Comment: I don't have a particular idea but if I were to put more precisely what we are looking for , it would be what is the "motivation" behind choosing fractional changes

Comment: Well, the motivation is the observation that such 'fractional changes' were actually useful in solving problems. Since we express them as differential equations, using differentials (fractional changes) is appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by differential equations? In my textbook we are taught to memorize them as ratios. What really is so special about fractional change rather than say a direct change of $\delta$

Comment: Fine. The full complete relationships are differential equations. Introductory courses may simplify to avoid all the math.